# How to play audio on the all platforms (including web) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, flutter-web

The [current audio plugins](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-add-music-audio-to-your-flutter-app-dcb6162c32d7) don't support the web. Assuming I have a local audio file or remote url, how would I play that on all platforms?

*I found a solution using [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) so I am sharing this below as a self-answer Q&A.*

Answer (score 12):

Flutter's [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin also supports audio, so you can use that. It currently supports Android, iOS, and the Web and will likely support other platforms as they become stable.

Here is the [Video Player cookbook example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video) adapted to play an audio file. I replaced the mp4 link with an mp3 link and removed the AspectRatio widget that the video needed. (Don't forget to add the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player#-installing-tab-) dependency to *pubspec.yaml*.)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoPlayerApp());

class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoPlayerScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    // Using an mp3 file instead of mp4.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3',
    );

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    _controller.setLooping(true);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Butterfly Video'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // not wrapped in an AspectRatio widget
            return VideoPlayer(_controller);
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              _controller.play();
            }
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To support the web, you need to add the [video_player_web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web) dependency as well.

```
dependencies:
  video_player: ^0.10.4
  video_player_web:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
      path: packages/video_player/video_player_web
```

Note that this will not use git in the future. See the explanation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web).

**Update:** Actually it worked on the web without specifying `video_player_web`.

**Update 2**: Read [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-audio-player-24bded45b928) for a workaround for Web.

**Update 3**: [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) is looking like a good solution.

**Update 4**: [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) *is* a good solution. I'm using it on Android, iOS, web, and macOS.

Comment: The official position from the Flutter team seems to be that the VideoPlayer is not designed for playing audio: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38480 In particular it fails to play files from assets.

Comment: @Suragch I am facing only one problem, that to on ios, audio file plays without sound.

Comment: @princeoo7, in my current project I switched to using the [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) plugin for Android and iOS.

Comment: @Suragch to play audio files from url, any working example that can you share ? I did tried that but failed to get it working when the audio is to be played from a url :(

Comment: @princeoo7, I was having trouble with that, too, so I downloaded the file first and then played it as a local file.

Comment: just_audio works fine for me. Since audioplayers package doesn't work for local assets for the web anymore, just_audio package is a good replacement.

Comment: @cmaxetom, I've also switched to using just_audio. It's working well on Android, iOS, the web and macOS.